# Laravel Auth with Vuejs, what i need to do with cookies?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, vuex

I past all day to learn the Auth methods for laravel but i keep not understand !

I got a project laravel/vuejs, i need to login a user and autorize or not on pages.

There is my methods for register and login :
(UserController)

```
public function login(Request $request){
    if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], true)){
        return Auth::check();
    }else {
        return 'error';
    }
}

public function register(Request $request){
    $user = new User();

    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->phone = $request->phone;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

    $user->role = 'Client';
    $user->save();

    Auth::login($user);

    return Auth::user();
}
```

Everything work so i got the data of Auth::chek() and is true. But now i have a router in route.js :

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Index,
  },
  {   
    name: 'Login',
    path: '/connexion',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/inscription',
    component: SignUp,
  },
  {
    path: '/accueil',
    component: Home,
  }
]
```

I want for example the user cannot access to login if is login. I know there is a midleware but i think the best way is to store a token in a vueX store.

But i got two Cookies created on app running : "laravel_session" and "XSRF-TOKEN". If my user login i got a "remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f01" and all other is update with new value.

Thanks for you'r time and sorry about my english language =/, i really want to understand correctly that for after not stay three days and doing nothing :(.

Comment: Are you using vue with an app generated with the vue-cli accessing laravel via api, or, you are serving php pages with vue components inside?

Comment: Hi, I' have a welcome.blade.php where i render my div id App and my component index.

But all app is in vuejs with a .vue (Login.vue, Home.vue ...)